# how to use contacts.getLocated() from Telegram API with telethon?

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I want to use the new "People nearby" feature from Telegram. I want to do it in python so I found [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon).
Then, I looked at the Telegram API and found the `contacts.getLocated()` method.
https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getLocated

But this method is not available in the Telethon library I think. Or at least I didnt found how to call it.

```
from telethon import functions
functions.contacts.getLocated()
```

gave me:
`AttributeError: module 'telethon.tl.functions.contacts' has no attribute 'getLocated'`

Can I call this method in any other way? Do I even have to use Telethon for this?

Comment: Telethon uses more Pythonic names for these methods, which you can find in https://tl.telethon.dev/.

Comment: here you got it https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/get_located.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Telethon documentation on full API](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/full-api.html) explains how to use all of the raw Telegram methods have to offer. [Searching for "get located"](https://tl.telethon.dev/?q=get%20located) we find [`GetLocatedRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/get_located.html). There is a button to copy the import, and also example code at the bottom:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.GetLocatedRequest(
        geo_point=types.InputGeoPoint(
            lat=7.13,
            long=7.13
        ),
        self_expires=42
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```

Needless to say you need to pass the right values in the geo point.

Comment: Ok i got it working, but it doesnt really care about the geo_point argument. Somehow it uses the location of my phone. Maybe this function does not do exactly what i was thinking.

Comment: No idea on that, with raw API you're talking directly with Telegram's API. What you send is what Telegram gets, and what you get is what Telegram sends (Telethon doesn't modify the requests beyond adapting the types to be correct).

Comment: It seems like the Telegram API has some background restrictions on how big the difference between to points in a timeframe can be . Via try and error I found out thats roughly 100m per 10s i think. So you can not pick just any point it seems. It has to be within a reasonable circle around your last position.