# Does python-telegram-bot have contacts.getLocated() implemented?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I want to get a list of nearby people by the location I have
like described here with telethon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563770/how-to-use-contacts-getlocated-from-telegram-api-with-telethon)
but I want to get a list of users that are nearby (the list telegram shows in nearby people) with telegram library (python-telegram-bot)
any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does python-telegram-bot have contacts.getLocated() implemented?

No. `python-telgeram-bot` is a wrapper for the Telegram Bot API, not for MTProto. See this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#can-you-add-feature-to-ptb-can-i-do-thing-with-my-bot).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: it says "PTB can only provide methods that are available through the API" and I think [this method](https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.getLocated) has nothing to do with MTProto. but I guess it's out of the bot's access. so how can i use that method in python?

Comment: It also says "You can find a full list of all available methods in the [official docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-methods)", where `getLocated` can not be found ;)

Comment: true. any guide for "so how can i use that method in python?" part?

Comment: If you want to use MTProto methods in python, you'll have to use a corresponding library like telethon or pyrogram. python-telegram-bot is just not such a library ;)

Comment: I tried to use telethon but it has error logging in (telegram side) so I guess I need to give pyrogram a try.
thanks for answering